# What is the WebApplicationContext in Spring MVC? What is it used for?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, applicationcontext

I know what the Spring ApplicationContext is, but I'm confused about the WebApplicationContext from Spring MVC. Can you guys help me?

- What is the WebApplicationContext?
- Why is it necessary?
- What is it used for?

Comment: I'll suggest you do some reading first, for example https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-applicationcontext-and-webapplicationcontext-in-spring-mvc/ and then come with a concrete question

Answer (score 1):

You can checkout `WebApplicationContext` codes for insight :

```java
public interface WebApplicationContext extends ApplicationContext {

   ServletContext getServletContext();
}
```

Because of the inheritance , you can simply think that `WebApplicationContext` is just a special kind of `ApplicationContext` which is used for the web application only. So all things that can be done by the `ApplicationContext` can also be done by the `WebApplicationContext`. But `WebApplicationContext` just provides one extra function which allow you to access the underlying `ServletContext` defined by the Servlet API specification.

It is necessary mainly because of the good OOP design. If we do not divide it into two interfaces but just add `getServletContext()` to the `ApplicationContext` and use it for all the non-web and web applications, it is awkward that the for the non-web application , we still need to include the Servlet API JAR to our project because we makes `ApplicationContext` depends on Servlet API.

Comment: Very good! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The official Spring [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.0.RC3/spring-framework-reference/web.html#spring-web) contains the answer.

> The WebApplicationContext is an extension of the plain ApplicationContext that has some extra features necessary for web applications. It differs from a normal ApplicationContext in that it is capable of resolving themes (see Using themes), and that it knows which Servlet it is associated with (by having a link to the ServletContext). The WebApplicationContext is bound in the ServletContext, and by using static methods on the RequestContextUtils class you can always look up the WebApplicationContext if you need access to it.

It is used to facilitate web server functionality. [Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.0.RC3/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-servlet-special-bean-types) also goes on to mention special beans types the WebApplicationContext provides. For example, a MultiPartResolver that "parses multi-part requests for example to support processing file uploads from HTML forms."

Comment: Very good, thank you for your explanation!

Comment: @DarkDefender it would be greatly appreciated if you used the voting mechanism to express your gratitude. Also, accepting an answer is highly advised.